# Get checkboxlist selected value on server side in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am updating checkboxlist value on the client side on click of another checkbox.
On button click when I try to get selected values on server side it returns false even though values are checked on the client side. chkboxList is databound on serverside.

Following is the sample code

ASPX page definition:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" runat="server" class="col-md-2 control-label" onclick="checkedAll()" />
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Select All </label>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxList"  runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="true" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkedAll() {
    var checkedItems = true;
    var list = document.getElementById("<%=chkboxList.ClientID%>");
    var chklist = list.getElementsByTagName("input");    
    for (var i = 0; i < chklist.length; i++) {
        if (chklist[i].type == "checkbox") {
            chklist[i].checked = checkedItems;
         }
    }
}
```

Server side on button click:

```
List<string> checkedItems = chkboxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(n => n.Selected))
         .Select(n => n.Value)
         .ToList();
```

checkedItems is returning "0" even when the checkboxes are checked on the client side.

Comment: Likely unrelated, but your onclick code doesn't compile, there's an extra bracket on `Selected))`.

Comment: that might be while copy pasting and editing in here..